# Android: In 4.4, Paint.measureText() is not backwards compatible. Any workarounds?

Tags: android

It is crucial for my app to be able to accurately measure Strings; I have been using `Paint.measureText()` to do this.  Unfortunately, in 4.4, this method was changed to no longer return a precise value, instead it returns a up-rounded value.  Is anyone aware of another method I can use to precisely measure text, or have any other suggestions?

Android source:

```
Android 17
  return w*mInvCompatScaling;
Android 18
  return (float) Math.ceil(w*mInvCompatScaling);
```

Comment: you probably can use reflexion to access mInvCompatScaling and native_measureText.

Comment: Yikes, that's a pretty major change for what really feels like an issue elsewhere: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/8e04840f38a16f806754dfca3de50c2548e67913. Have you tried invoking `native_measureText` via reflection as njzk2 suggests?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the use case for sub-pixel measurement of text lengths? Perhaps there is some other solution to your larger use case.

Comment: I tried reflection, but I'm getting an error.  Does anyone know why the following throws a NoSuchMethodException? :       Method m = MyPaint.class.getDeclaredMethod("native_measureText", new Class[] { String.class, Integer.class });

Comment: @ab11 did you resolve the above issue?

Comment: Well, I ended up just adjusting my measurements so that the rounding error didn't effect me.  So, if I'm measuring text with .1 text size, I just multiply it by 100 before measuring it, and dividing the resultant measurement by 100.  It's a messy and (slightly) inefficient solution, but works fine for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks falling back to reflection is the only way to get back old functionality. Lookup private native method as following and invoke it.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
// configure paint here

Method m = paint.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("native_measureText", 
               String.class, int.class);
float size = m.invoke(paint, text, 0x2);
             // text - text to measure
             // 0x2 - default for Right-To-Left text
```

Although it doesn't look very clean, this must work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You must set:

```
m.setAccessible(true);
```

before invoking it not to get `IllegalAccessException`.